# django Inheriting from helper class

Tags: python, django, oop

I wanted to make wallets for BTC and LTC coins in my models. But since most of the code will be same apart from the `coin_name` and `tx_fees`. 
So, I thought of making a helper class like this :

**Wallet class** ( snippet )

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, editable=False)
    trading_amt = models.FloatField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), ])
    wallet_amt = models.FloatField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), ])
    wallet_address = models.CharField(default='', blank=True, max_length=100)
    coin_name = ''  <-- will it serve the purpose ?
    tx_fee = 0      <-- and this ?

    def __init__(self, coin_name, tx_fee):
        self.coin_name = coin_name
        self.tx_fee = tx_fee

    @transaction.atomic
    def moveToTrading(self, amount):
        if amount > self.wallet_amt:
            return "Insufficient balance"
        else:
            self.trading_amt += amount
            self.wallet_amt -= amount
            return True

    @transaction.atomic
    def withdraw(self, amount, withdrawal_wallet_addr):
        if amount > self.wallet_amt:
            return "Insufficient balance"
        else:
            # First check if withdrawal address entered by user is
            # correct, using wallet daemon , if not return error
            if check_wallet(withdrawal_wallet_addr, "btc"):
                # initiate checkout
                return initiate_checkout(withdrawal_wallet_addr, self.coin_name, self.tx_fee)
            else:
                return "Incorrect Wallet address"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = gen_random_string('btc_wallet')
        super(Wallet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.wallet_amt += amount

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The use of `coin_name` is only while creating wallet address `name` like this : _btc_wallet_<64 char random string>_
And `tx_fee` is stored as a constant in **helpers.py** for each coin.
So, saving these in the database doesn't makes sense.

### Problem 1 :

I am a little noob in OOP programming ( I know what these are , but haven't coded much ) so am confused as to what would be it's correct usage :

#### Usage 1 :

```
class BtcWallet(Wallet):
    def __init__(self, coin_name, tx_fee):
        self.tx_fee = BTC_FEES
        self.coin_name = "BTC"
        super(BtcWallet, self).__init__(coin_name, tx_fee)
```

#### OR

```
class BtcWallet(Wallet):
    def __init__(self, coin_name, tx_fee):
        self.tx_fee = BTC_FEES
        self.coin_name = "BTC"
```

i.e. do I need to initialise the **super initialiser** ?

Also if super is used then how should it be used, like :

```
super(BtcWallet, self).__init__(coin_name, tx_fee)
```

**or**

```
super(Wallet, self).__init__(coin_name, tx_fee)
```

### Problem 2 :

Since `coin_name` and `tx_fees` isn't saved in the database, so when could it fail ? Like when would it not take the values.

Perhaps, it shouldn't fail cause always there would be an object of this wherever it would be used ?

The `BtcWallet` is a foreign key element of **userprofile** model.would it fail if I use it like this
 `request.user.profile.BTC_wallet.withdraw()`
( I may use it in one of the views )

**UserProfile model**  ( snippet )

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    joining_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    BTC_wallet = models.OneToOneField(BtcWallet, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='profile', null=True,
                                      blank=True)
```

### Update :

After changing to new form ( earlier there wasn't any wallet class in my code and the wallet class was the BtcWallet class ) and making migrations results into this :

```
jame@vostro:~/mywebsite# python manage.py makemigrations account
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'wallet_ptr' to btcwallet without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

Answer (score 0):

Well **__pycache__**, one of the guys on #django , helped me figure this out.

The wallet class needed to be an **Abstract class** [Meta Class options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.abstract) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) about the abstract classes.

### Reason

Abstract classes aren't made into table models and serve the purpose as helper class.

#### The new code

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, editable=False)
    trading_amt = models.FloatField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), ])
    wallet_amt = models.FloatField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), ])
    wallet_address = models.CharField(default='', blank=True, max_length=100)
    coin_name = ''
    tx_fee = 0

    @transaction.atomic
    def moveToTrading(self, amount):
        if amount > self.wallet_amt:
            return "Insufficient balance"
        else:
            self.trading_amt += amount
            self.wallet_amt -= amount
            return True

    @transaction.atomic
    def withdraw(self, amount, withdrawal_wallet_addr):
        if amount > self.wallet_amt:
            return "Insufficient balance"
        else:
            # First check if withdrawal address entered by user is
            # correct, using wallet daemon , if not return error
            if check_wallet(withdrawal_wallet_addr, self.coin_name):
                # initiate checkout
                return initiate_checkout(withdrawal_wallet_addr, self.coin_name, self.tx_fee)
            else:
                return "Incorrect Wallet address"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = gen_random_string(self.coin_name.lower()+'_wallet')
        super(Wallet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.wallet_amt += amount

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:                 <-------Added this
        abstract = True
```

**And for BtcWallet class : **

```
class BtcWallet(Wallet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.coin_name = "BTC"
        self.tx_fee = COINS[self.coin_name]['tx_fee']
        super(BtcWallet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

### Note

`super` needs to be called, cause we're overriding the **init** method and it needs to be called for every function that's being overriden.

```
Python 2.x --> super(subclassName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
Python 3.x --> super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Check out [this nice article](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) by Raymond Hettinger on **super** , quite helpful and clear.